# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\pi}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

**Question :**

> Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\pi}$

[Wolfram Alpha says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2F%28n*pi%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) $\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1{n\pi}=\frac{H_m}{π}$ where $H_m$ equals $m^{th}$ harmonic number.

Can anybody help me derive it and explain why it is so?
Being a high-schooler, please don't think I am dumb!

Comment: $H_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n$. It diverges.

Comment: @Student1058 Thanks for editing it, you know, still a high school guy, so still gotta learn some things :)

Comment: @PrateekKulkarni Make sure to check out [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a MathJax tutoral.

Comment: @Student1058 sure I will do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for each $N\in\Bbb N$,$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{\pi n}=\frac1\pi\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n.$$But$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n=\infty;$$in other words, the harmonic series diverges. So, your sum doesn't exist (in $\Bbb R$).